# Asnchronous task not working in Android 3.0 - 4.0

Tags: android

I am working in the project which is parsing the values data and displaying using xml parsing.

It was working fine in android version upto 2.3 but not working upto 4.0.

I found, In asynchronous task onPreExeucte method is working well but when the process reaches the doInBackground method it will not working.And showing null exception line number 251.

Here is my code, help me to solve this problem.

```
public class AsynTaskScoreboard extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "Retrieving data ", " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL xpto = new URL(strMainUrl + "score.php?UserId=" + EventListActivity.UserID);

            Log.e("Total urlScore board", "scr bord full url " + xpto);
            HttpURLConnection conn;

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) xpto.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            try {

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(is);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList nodeList;

                nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TotalPoints");
                Node node1 = nodeList.item(0);
                Element fstElmnt1 = (Element) node1;
                NodeList scoreList1 = fstElmnt1.getElementsByTagName("TotalPoints");
                Element scoreElement1 = (Element) scoreList1.item(0);
                scoreList1 = scoreElement1.getChildNodes();
                strTotalPoints = ((Node) scoreList1.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                Log.d("SetText", "strTotalPoints " + strTotalPoints);

                nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ChallengesPlayed");
                node1 = nodeList.item(0);
                fstElmnt1 = (Element) node1;
                scoreList1 = fstElmnt1.getElementsByTagName("ChallengesPlayed");
                scoreElement1 = (Element) scoreList1.item(0);
                scoreList1 = scoreElement1.getChildNodes();
                strChallengesPoint = ((Node) scoreList1.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                Log.d("SetText", "strChallengesPoint " + strChallengesPoint);

                android.os.Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.what = 11;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);

                /**
                 * Check whether it is my points or high score
                 */
                switch (flagMypointsOrHighScore) {
                case 0:
                    nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("UserScore");

                    // Define Array based on nodelist

                    arrLength = nodeList.getLength();
                    strGameid = new String[arrLength];
                    strGameNameArr = new String[arrLength];
                    strGameLocationArr = new String[arrLength];
                    strGameDate = new String[arrLength];

                    Log.d("SetText", "arrLength " + arrLength);
                    Log.d("SetText", "strGameid " + strGameid);
                    Log.d("SetText", "strGameNameArr " + strGameNameArr);
                    Log.d("SetText", "strGameLocationArr " + strGameLocationArr);
                    Log.d("SetText", "strGameDate " + strGameDate);

                    String[] strXMLTag = { "GameId", "GameName", "Location", "Date" };
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {

                        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                        Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                        for (int j = 0; j < strXMLTag.length; j++) {
                            NodeList scoreList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName(strXMLTag[j]);
                            Element scoreElement = (Element) scoreList.item(0);
                            scoreList = scoreElement.getChildNodes();
                            switch (j) {
                            case 0:
                                strGameid[i] = ((Node) scoreList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                strGameNameArr[i] = ((Node) scoreList.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                                break;
                            case 2:
                                strGameLocationArr[i] = ((Node) scoreList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                                // location =
                                // strGameLocationArr[i].toString().trim();
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                strGameDate[i] = ((Node) scoreList.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    }// End of for loop
                        // Your rank

                    break;

                case 1:// Top rank 5

                    nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Top5Rank");

                    // Define Array based on nodelist

                    arrLength = nodeList.getLength();
                    strGameNameArr = new String[arrLength];
                    strGameLocationArr = new String[arrLength];
                    strGameDate = new String[arrLength];
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {

                        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                        Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                        NodeList rankList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Person");
                        //
                        int rankListLength = rankList.getLength();

                        if (strPersonNameArr == null) {
                            strPersonNameArr = new String[rankListLength];
                            strPersonRankArr = new String[rankListLength];
                            strPersoonPointsArr = new String[rankListLength];
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < rankListLength; j++) {
                            rankList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Person");
                            Element rankElement = (Element) rankList.item(j);
                            rankList = rankElement.getChildNodes();
                            strPersonNameArr[j] = rankElement.getAttribute("Name");
                            strPersonRankArr[j] = rankElement.getAttribute("Rank");
                            strPersoonPointsArr[j] = rankElement.getAttribute("Points");
                        }

                    }// End of for loop

                    // // Your rank
                    //
                    // nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("YourRank");
                    //
                    // // Define Array based on nodelist
                    //
                    // for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
                    // //
                    // Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                    // Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                    //
                    // NodeList rankList = fstElmnt
                    // .getElementsByTagName("Person");
                    // Element rankElement = (Element) rankList.item(0);
                    // rankList = rankElement.getChildNodes();
                    // strPersonName = rankElement.getAttribute("Name");
                    // strRank = rankElement.getAttribute("Rank");
                    // strPoint = rankElement.getAttribute("Points");
                    //
                    // }// End of for loop
                    break;

                }// End of switch
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }// try below db 2try

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            if (e.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("java.net.SocketException: Network unreachable")) {
                android.os.Message msg = android.os.Message.obtain();
                msg.what = 0;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }// End of do in background method

    // do the stuff after the heavy task

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        android.os.Message msg = Message.obtain();
        switch (flagMypointsOrHighScore) {
        case 0:
            listViewMyPoints.setAdapter(new JR_LB_ListAdapter(ScoreboardActivity.this));
            break;
        case 1:
            listViewHighScores.setAdapter(new JR_LB_ListAdapter_HighScores(ScoreboardActivity.this));
            // Set textview value in the
            msg.what = 10;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
            break;
        default:

        }

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }// End of on post execute method

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Totalpoint.setText(strTotalPoints);
        challengeplay.setText(strChallengesPoint);
        txtViewRank.setText(strRank);
        txtViewPoint.setText(strPoint);
        txtViewPersonName.setText(strPersonName);

    }

}// End of Asynchronous task class
```

Comment: what is there in line number 251?

Comment: strTotalPoints = ((Node) scoreList1.item(0)).getNodeValue(); while getting "TotalPoints" tag.